# trying to get 2 websites on one server with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Ok I've been looking around for a while and I'm pretty sure I have the virtualhost file configured properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ScriptAlias /cgi/ /var/www/html/cgi-bin/

<Directory /var/www/html/cgi-bin/>
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.net
Redirect permanent http://www.example.net/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
Redirect permanent http://www.test.com/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is one .conf file. Hopefully I can get 3 sites working on one ip address. I've looked around, and everything says that this should be working, but it's not. Typing in any of the domain names in on a browser only ever reveals one website, no matter what the DocumentRoot is set to.

Is there some other setting I should no about. Should I have multiple .conf files enabled. Should I work off of different ports.

Why is this not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have two VirtualHosts, one redirecting visitors to www.example.net and one to www.test.com, but it does not look like you have configured any vhosts to serve requests to those hosts, so those requests are all being fielded by the default vhost.

Comment: I was thinking it might be something like that, but am not sure what my next move is. could you advise

Comment: You need to define virtualhosts that serve requests to those hosts.

Comment: i dont follow. do i need to define redirects differently, because i put those in to avoid the errors i get from the servername not always resolving to the same name in the request.

Comment: Read up on how name-based virtual hosting works. You are redirecting to a host name that your apache instance knows nothing about. So modify your configuration to let your server know about the other hostnames it should be expecting.

Comment: is that the .htaccess file

Comment: No it is not - virtualhosts are not defined in .htaccess files. Again, read up on the topic so you can make informed decisions.

Comment: i am reading. should i go to my dns provider and add a records. because i think i have already done that correctly